# Android x86 isn't working in virtualbox

Tags: android-x86, virtualbox

I have installed android x86 in virtualbox. But its not booting now.

After installation it pop up a message "Android x86 installed successfully". Then I power off the vm and remove the iso image from it and then power on. When booting the os it only shows this. (This display has been there for 1 hour.)

[image: This is the display]

Comment: Make sure you are using the 64bit version, according to a lot of post here over the years, this error is [common to Android-x86](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-x86) and occurs more often in the 32bit version. Besides that I assume that VirtualBox graphics system is simply not supported by Android-x86. Keep in mind that it is a non-commercial community project.

Comment: @Robert I have used 64bit

Comment: What is your CPU and GPU model ? Old CPU doesn't support SSE commands and doesn't run new version of android-x86.